# How to execute php code at cli?

Tags: php

I want to run simple code at cli and check the value of php setting max_execution_time. Of course I can check it at php.ini or .htaccess. I tried to do it using cli

```
php -a
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

but it return 0 always. Is there any way to check it at cli?

Comment: You realize you're *setting* `max_execution_time`, right? That's what `ini_**set**` means.

Comment: Do you mean to use `ini_get`?  Why isn't it possible for the value to be `0`?  That just means no execution time limit.

Comment: Also, since you don't include the *required* second parameter of `ini_set` it fails, and returns 0. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: sorry, I mean `ini_get`, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `0` is because you're `echo`ing the result of `ini_set('max_execution_time')`.

Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), `ini_set()` requres ***two*** parameters, and returns `FALSE` upon failure. By providing only one parameter, you cause the function to return `FALSE` every time.

If you want to **get** the value of `max_execution_time` you should call [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to check for execution time

```
linux-1:~$ php -i | grep max_execution
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is **get** the value from the ini configuration.  For that you'll need to use [`ini_get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php)

A max execution time of zero simply means that there is no limit.  The script will never timeout.  This is the default behavior when running PHP from the command line

Taken from the [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) -

> #### max_execution_time -
>
> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. **When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.**

Comment: When `ini_set` returns 0, it means that it failed. There are two parameters that are required and OP only passes one parameter.